# how to display webview current url stored in string in dialog box - android

Tags: android

I am trying to get Web View current URL in dialog box.

I used following code, but its giving error

```
String webUrl1 = web.getUrl();
builder.setMessage(webUrl1);
```

here is full code.

i am trying to match url in if condition. but it doesn't giving any error nor working properly.

```
    //setting up web view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    setUpWebView();
    web.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

    String webUrl1 = web.getUrl();

    if (webUrl1=="http://www.example.com"){
    //do something.
    }
```

Comment: builder cannot be resolved

Comment: Please post the code where you are creating the dialog box

Comment: @Rohit5k2 please check above code.

Comment: @FAAD: please check if the webview is redirected to "domain.com/", so "domain.com" won't match...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how we compare strings in java. Change this

```
if (webUrl1=="http://www.example.com"){
```

with

```
if (webUrl1.equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.example.com")){
```

Comment: but this should not lead to OP's error.

Comment: He never mentioned he is getting any specific error. See OP's comments. It simply means its not working.

Comment: I guess his last issue with builder is resolved. Please see the question,

Comment: yes no error let me try..

Comment: no doesn't work... now not opening the app getting message "unfortunately , app has stopped"

Comment: It means your code is working now; Just not the way it was supposed to. Please post the logcat error output.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i found the error... String webUrl1 = web.getUrl(); not getting current url from the webview.... when i passed direct text into string it works...